# OpenFire integrating external database

Tags: mysql, database, xmpp, openfire

Hi i am having trouble integrating my exsisting OpenFire installtion with an already existing DB.

I have 2 database namely (for example purposes)

1. db_mainsite
2. db_openfire

Inside my db_mainsite i have a table called tbl_user where there lies 2 columns namely gw_userunique and gw_password (VARCHAR 255, however using SHA-1 hashing algo).

Both database lies within the same machine (server) thus having the same physical location.

In my conf/openfire.xml i have set the following lines

```
<jive>
  ...
  <jdbcProvider>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <connectionString>jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_mainsite?user=username&amp;password=secret</connectionString>
  </jdbcProvider>
  <provider>
    <auth>
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider</className>
    </auth>
  </provider>
  <jdbcAuthProvider>
   <passwordSQL>SELECT password FROM tbl_user WHERE gw_userunique=?</passwordSQL>
   <passwordType>sha1</passwordType>
  </jdbcAuthProvider>
  ...
</jive>
```

Sadly, whenever i try to login using the username + password stored in db_mainsite it always  fails.

I have restart OpenFire as well.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to modify config file, just run script in your openfire database( validated in  3.10.3):

```
## add jdbc drive
INSERT INTO `ofproperty` VALUES ('jdbcProvider.driver', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver');
## external membership database connection 
INSERT INTO `ofproperty` VALUES ('jdbcProvider.connectionString', 'jdbc:mysql://youripaddress:3306/db_mainsite?user=root&password=root');
## auth 
UPDATE `ofproperty` SET  propValue='org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider'  WHERE     NAME='provider.auth.className';
## search password
 INSERT INTO `ofproperty` VALUES ('jdbcAuthProvider.passwordSQL', 'SELECT  plainPassword FROM dzmembership WHERE id= ?');
## encrypted type：plain，md5，sha1，sha256，sha512
INSERT INTO `ofproperty` VALUES ('jdbcAuthProvider.passwordType', 'plain');
## displyed in admin console
UPDATE  `ofproperty` SET propValue='org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.JDBCUserProvider' WHERE NAME='provider.user.className';
## uyser info in admin console 
INSERT INTO `ofproperty` VALUES ('jdbcUserProvider.loadUserSQL', 'SELECT username AS NAME,concat(username,''_'',nickname) FROM dzmembership WHERE id=?');
## user amount 
INSERT INTO `ofproperty` VALUES ('jdbcUserProvider.userCountSQL', 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dzmembership');
## all users 
INSERT INTO `ofproperty` VALUES ('jdbcUserProvider.allUsersSQL', 'SELECT id FROM dzmembership');
## search 
INSERT INTO `ofproperty` VALUES ('jdbcUserProvider.searchSQL', 'SELECT id FROM dzmembership WHERE');
## username displayed in console
INSERT INTO `ofproperty` VALUES ('jdbcUserProvider.usernameField', 'username');
## id  displayed in console
 INSERT INTO `ofproperty` VALUES ('jdbcUserProvider.nameField', 'id');
## email displayed in console
INSERT INTO `ofproperty` VALUES ('jdbcUserProvider.emailField', 'email');
##admin username
INSERT INTO `ofproperty` VALUES ('admin.authorizedJIDs', '13cb2932-e855-4c3e-8e54-a58e0135802d@ipaddress');
UPDATE ofproperty SET propValue='ipaddress' WHERE NAME='xmpp.domain'
```